# android equivalent of iOS's imageView.addArrayOfImages()

Tags: android, ios, uiimageview, android-imageview

Is there an android equivalent to iOS' UIImageView method that allows you to provide an array of images, and then it will cycle through the images?  Like a slideshow or gif.

If not, what is the best method, or control, that mimics this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just  throw in my 2 cents...

I don't see why you couldn't use an `ArrayList<ImageView>` to do this. You can add any type of object to it and you can cycle through the list easily. You can create you own method in a second. (Keep in mind, I'm not sure how `UIImageView` works)

Comment: yea i could always get a timer and change the image every time it fires...  i was wondering if such a thing existed in the android world

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't used or heard of such a method. Maybe it exists, not sure. My knowledge is not that vast :) Sorry